# reduction of RDDs in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, reduce

I have an RDD (session ID, session start-time, session length)..I need to reduce this RDD by session ID however then to generate an array of corresponding session start times and lengths as well. Can someone point me how to write the code in scala?

so I need to convert from RDD[(session ID , session start-time, session length)]
to RDD[(session ID , Seq[(session start-time, session length)])
how can I do this?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe `groupBy` could help (although it's not very recommended as it can be slow):

```
val a = sc.parallelize(Seq(("a", 0, 0), ("b", 1, 1), ("a", 2, 2)))
val grouped = a.groupBy{ case(sessionID, startTime, length) => sessionID }
```

In this case, `grouped` will be an `RDD[(String, Iterable[(String, Int, Int)]`. Then you can easily map it to get the format you want.

**Alternatively**, you could use `map` + `groupByKey`:

```
val grouped = a.map { 
  case(sessionID, startTime, length) => (sessionID, (startTime, length)) 
}.groupByKey
```